# Authorising several google APIs in the same without browser

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script which has to pull data from Google Drive, Bigquery and then pipe it to a Google Sheets.

I've managed to authenticate in Bigquery and Google sheets without a browser, but I can't find any clear information about how to do that in Google Drive, and more importantly, how to do it in a neat way so the stored service account works with all three.

Here is what I have for Bigquery

```
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    {
        -InfoService account
  },
)
credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    [
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
     ],
     )

sql = """sqlquery"""
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, credentials=credentials)
```

And for google sheets

```
auth_key = {
  "client_id": "id",
  "client_secret": "secret",
  "refresh_token": "token"
}

credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
    access_token=None,
    client_id=auth_key['client_id'],
    client_secret=auth_key['client_secret'],
    refresh_token=auth_key['refresh_token'],
    token_expiry=None,
    token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
    user_agent=None,
    revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI)

credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
cred = json.loads(credentials.to_json())
cred['type'] = 'authorized_user'

with open('adc.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(cred, outfile)

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = credentials
client = gspread.authorize(gauth.credentials)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried for Drive? Have you authorized it for the same Service Account in [Google Admin](https://admin.google.com/)?

Comment: I haven't tried with Drive, because I can't find a way of using the same credentials I have for either BQ or sheets.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for a way to use service account for Drive API. Did you check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority)? I believe this may be what you are looking for. Let me know!